# How to start another thread in request handling thread with Flask?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, flask, dbcontext

First of all, I have tried looking for answers in this website. But no luck...

What I wanna achieve is that starting an independent thread in  the request handling thread to do some asynchronous  task. The tricky point is that there are some database operations needed in this independent thread.

Here is an example. Five files included.

```
project
    |__manager.py
    |__config.py
    |__deployer
           |__`__init__.py`
           |__models.py
           |__views.py
           |__operators.py
```

Detail code below...

```
# deployer/__init__.py
from flask import Flask
from deployer.models import db

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(object_name)

    db.init_app(app)

    # Add route for index
    @app.route('/')
    def index():
        return {'code': 200, 'message': 'OK'}

    return app

# manager.py
from os import environ
from flask_script import Manager, Server
from deployer import create_app
from flask_restful import Api
from deployer.views import HostView

env = environ.get('APM_ENV', 'dev')
app = create_app('config.%sConfig' % env.capitalize())
api = Api(app)
api.add_resource(HostView, '/api/v1/hosts')

manager = Manager(app)
manager.add_command("server", Server(host='0.0.0.0', port=9527))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run(default_command='server')

# deployer/views.py
from flask_restful import Resource, reqparse
from flask import jsonify

from deployer.models import db, Host
from deployer.operators import HostInitiator

parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('host', type=int, help='Specify an unique host.')


class HostView(Resource):
    def get(self):
        h = db.session.query(Host).filter(Host.id == 1).one()
        return jsonify(
            host_id=h.id,
            host_code=h.code,
            host_ip=h.ip_addr_v4
        )
    
    def post(self):
        h = Host(
        code='Harbor',
        ip_addr_v4='10.10.10.199',
        state='created'
        )
    
        db.session.add(h)
        db.session.commit()

        initiator = HostInitiator(host=h)
        initiator.start()
    
        return {
            'code': 'Harbor',
            'ip_addr_v4': '10.10.10.199',
            'state': 'created'
        }

# deployer/models.py
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()

class Host(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'br_host'
    
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    code = Column(String(128), index=True, nullable=False)
    ip_addr_v4 = Column(String(15), nullable=False)
    state = Column(String(16), nullable=False)


# deployer/operators.py
from threading import Thread
from deployer.models import db

class HostInitiator(Thread):
    def __init__(self, host):
        super().__init__()
        self.host = host

    def run(self):
        # Update Host.state [created-->initating]
        db.session.query(Host).filter(Host.id == self.host.id).update({'state': 'initating'})
        db.session.commit()

        # do some initiating things...

        # Update Host.state [initating-->ready]
        db.session.query(Host).filter(Host.id == self.host.id).update({'state': 'ready'})
        db.session.commit()
```

Always got `outside application context` error with code above. The error message indicates that no database operation is permitted in the `HostInitiator` thread.
It suggests me to push a context or move my code into a view function. I'm suffering this quite a while, please help out if you guys have any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code works for me

```py
def test_multi_threading_query():
    # module which i create Flask app instance
    from app.main import app
    # module which i create sqlalchemhy instance
    from app.model.db import db, Post
    with app.app_context():
        posts = Post.query.all()
        p = posts[0]
        p.foo = 1
        db.session.add(p)
        db.session.commit()
        print(p)


@api.route('/test')
def test_view():
    from threading import Thread
    t = Thread(target=test_multi_threading_query)
    t.start()
    return ''


# main.py
app = Flask(__main__)

#db.py
db = SQLAlchemy()

class Post(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    foo = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

[image]

https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/appcontext/

Comment: You mean try to import `create_app` from deployer/__init__.py, and get initiator thread started in its(app object) context? See `with create_app('config.DevConfig').app_context()` ? I've tried this. Not work. Same error.

Comment: i change my answer,that works for me, hopes that helps you